# How to get the process ID of process started via execvp()

Tags: c, linux

I am new to linux programming and I would like to get some suggestions about killing a process which was started using `execvp()`. Following is the code which launches `"TestApplication"` as a child process. When the user interrupts (ctrl+C) I want to kill the `"TestApplication"` as well along with the parent process.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this. Pls. help. Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   signal(SIGINT, KillProcess); 

   pid_t pid;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid == -1)
   {
      printf("Error: Fork process failed");
      exit(-1);
   }
   else if (pid == 0)
   {
      char *const paramList[] = {"5"," 1", NULL};
      execvp("TestApplication", paramList);
   }
   else
   {
      // Wait for signal from the TestApplication process when successfully executed
   }
   return 0;
}

void KillProcess(int sig)
{
    // Want to get the process ID of "TestApplication"
    // Then force Kill it
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to get the process ID of process started via execvp() ?

`fork()` return value to parent is started child process `PID`.

If `fork()` sys_call doesn't fail, then `pid` variable in child process is 0 and in parent process is the `pid` of the spawned child. So if you want to know the child process pid you can just check the return value of `fork()` in parent process, which is stored in `pid`. In-order to get parent process `pid` you can just call `getpid()`.

Comment: `getpid()` returns the pid of the parent process. I would like to get the pid of the process which I just started. I just launched my program and checked the task manager to see the process IDs. I always get the ID for the parent process only.

Comment: @killer
If you check `pid` variable in parent process. i.e. in else statement, it is the actuall pid of the child process.

Comment: Thanks @Tony Tannous for pointing this out. I get the proper pid now. Cheers.